# Can't get styled button to line up with text beside it

Tags: css

Normally I wouldn't post here for such a small question but I've tried everything I can think of.  I've literally spent the past hour trying to make this work, vertical-align, padding up and down, etc.  I'm sure it's easy.

http://jsfiddle.net/vWzZz/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is `&{'views.overview.selectLocation'}` and what are you trying to get the button to vertically line up with? The pull-down?

Comment: Yea the pull down.  Sorry the weird text is locale messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "float:left" from your button and it will be centered.

If that's not an option in your deployed environment, surround all the labels in a new div and add a margin-top or padding-top to that div.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with some div and try inline

```
.someButton,.someText
{
display:inline-block;
}
<div class = "someButton">
    <input type=button />
</div>
<div class = "someText">
  some text .....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative margin on the top. The button is taller than the other items on the line because of the added padding and other box-model elements.

```
margin:-4px .7em 0 0;
```